# JSch: what am i doing wrong, with JSCH tty code for executing interactive commands?

Tags: java, ssh, jsch

I'm trying to connect with JSch to a server and then execute an interactive `su` command.

Could you please tell me what I am missing? This stuff hangs everytime, and I see no reason for that behavior.
Especially I am specifically waiting for the password string ( actually `assword` without `:` ) before sending in the password.

That is what I'm doing:

1. logs in as user1/pass1
2. then executes `su - user2 -c commandline`.
3. pass the password in the channel input stream.

Anyways, here's the main execute function, it takes user1/pass1, user2/pass2 and commandLine.

```
public String execute (String host, String nuser, String npass,
                       String puser, String ppass, String commandLine)
    {
      try{
        synchronized(this) 
        {
          session = jsch.getSession(nuser,host,22);
          session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
          pstr=npass;
          //session.setPassword(npass);
          String authmethods=  session.getConfig("PreferredAuthentications");
          System.out.println(authmethods);
          UserInfo ui=new SUSessionExecution.UInfo();
          Thread.sleep(150);
          if(authmethods.contains("keyboard-interactive"))
          { System.out.print("keyboard-interactive"); session.setUserInfo(ui); } 
          else if ( authmethods.contains("password") )
          { System.out.print("password"); session.setPassword(pstr);  }

          session.connect();
          channel = session.openChannel("exec");
          nuser=null;
          npass=null;


          ((ChannelExec)channel).setPty(true);
          ((ChannelExec)channel).setPtyType("vt100");
          String command= "su - " + puser + " -c " + commandLine  + "\n";
          //((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand(commandLine);

          byte[] cmdBuffer=command.getBytes();
          ByteArrayInputStream bi = new ByteArrayInputStream(cmdBuffer);
          channel.setInputStream(bi);

          ByteArrayOutputStream bo = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
          ((ChannelExec)channel).setErrStream(bo);

          sessionOutput = channel.getInputStream();
          //sessionError = channel.getExtInputStream();


          channel.connect();

          session_open=true;
          // it is only here our session is fully functional.

          boolean sustatus;//=establishSU(commandIO, channel,puser,ppass);
          // NEEDS REPLACE

          //commandIO.write(command.getBytes());
          //commandIO.flush();



          String standardOutBuffer="";
          String standardErrBuffer="";

          int counter;
          byte[] byteBuffer = new byte[1024];


          while(sessionOutput.available() > 0)
            { counter=0; //byteBuffer=null;
              counter=sessionOutput.read(byteBuffer, 0, byteBuffer.length);
              if(counter < 0) { throw new java.io.IOException(); }
              standardOutBuffer += new String(byteBuffer,0,counter);
              if(standardOutBuffer.contains("assword")){break;}
            }

            /*if(sessionError.available() > 0)
            { counter=0; //byteBuffer=null;
              counter=sessionError.read(byteBuffer, 0, byteBuffer.length);
              if(counter < 0) { throw new java.io.IOException(); }
              standardErrBuffer += new String(byteBuffer,0,counter);
              if(standardErrBuffer.contains("assword")){break;}}*/


        commandIO = new PipedOutputStream();
        sessionInput = new PipedInputStream(commandIO);
        channel.setInputStream(sessionInput);
        commandIO.write(new String(ppass+"\n").getBytes());
        commandIO.flush();

        counter=0; standardOutBuffer="";
        while((counter = sessionOutput.read(byteBuffer,0,byteBuffer.length)) != -1)
        { standardOutBuffer += new String(byteBuffer,0,counter); }

        closeComponents();
        return standardOutBuffer;
        }
      }
      catch(com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException jse) 
      { session_open=false;su_space_open=false;jse.printStackTrace();
        closeComponents(); return null; }
      catch(java.io.IOException ioe)
      { session_open=false;su_space_open=false;ioe.printStackTrace();
        closeComponents(); return null; }
      catch(InterruptedException ie)
      { ie.printStackTrace(); }

        return null;
    }
```

Here is my error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
  at com.jcraft.jsch.Buffer.putString(Buffer.java:59)
  at com.jcraft.jsch.UserAuthKeyboardInteractive.start(UserAuthKeyboardInteractive.ja‌va:183)
  at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:442)
  at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:162)
  at susessionexecution.SUExecute.execute(SUExecute.java:53)
  at Tester.<init>(Tester.java:12)
  at Tester.main(Tester.java:17)
```

and Here is the promptKeyboardInteractive method

```
public String[] promptKeyboardInteractive (String destination, String name,
                                           String instruction, String[] prompt,
                                           boolean[] echo)
{
    System.out.println("\n"+prompt.length+"\n\n");
    String[] response=new String[prompt.length];
    response[0] = passwd;
    return response;
}
```

Comment: between guys, here is the error message :

___________

        `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.jcraft.jsch.Buffer.putString(Buffer.java:59)
        at com.jcraft.jsch.UserAuthKeyboardInteractive.start(UserAuthKeyboardInteractive.java:183)
        at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:442)
        at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:162)
        at susessionexecution.SUExecute.execute(SUExecute.java:53)
        at Tester.<init>(Tester.java:12)
        at Tester.main(Tester.java:17)` 
_________________

Comment: Could you show the source code of your UInfo class? It looks like the error sits there.

Comment: Please don't put code in comments, it is not legible there. Edit your question instead. And why are you creating an array of length prompt.length, and filling only the first element of it?

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann because prompt.length mostly comes to 1, however, i have tried variable length arrays and send them as well. the result has been same. 

the interesting thing is it ran once, without giving error. i really don't see anything to do with timing here, but seeing this behavior now it seems to me, to have to do something with the timing.

thanks,
Chandan

Answer (score 0):

It seems your implementation of

```
  UIKeyboardInteractive#promptKeyboardInteractive()
```

returns an array of String, which contains 'null'.

As for sudo,  I suggest to refer to 
  http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Sudo.java.html

Comment: Thanks, I will look into the promptKeyboardInteractive hack again. as it can be seen from the code, it was a unpleasant hack to make it noninteractive.

Comment: In almost of all cases, session.setPassword(pstr) will work for "keyboard-interactive" auth method.  Have you tried it?

Comment: @paulo, hey many thanks for reformatting the question in nice order. looks a lot clearer.

Comment: i just checked the promptKeyboardInteractive() , making it simply pass out a string ( hence no way of sending null ), but, this error still shows up.

here's the poor test hack.

`public String[] promptKeyboardInteractive
        (String destination, String name,
         String instruction, String[] prompt,
         boolean[] echo)
      { 
       
       System.out.println("\n"+prompt.length+"\n\n");
       String[] response=new String[prompt.length];

       response[0] = passwd;
       
       return response;
     }` 


am trying few other things,  will keep this thread posted.

Comment: `session.setPassword(passwdStr)` -> @ymnk i tried this, in this usecase, we are dealing with a custom SSH service ( although just a modification/tightened one of the openssh ) , and it does not seem to take it. however sending a hack from the keyboard interactive works fine, and considers it as a valid keyboard interactive challenge response. 

i saw the code, theory i dont see a reason why it does not work. because on failure of password authentication, setPassword in this version automatically runs a neat keyboard interactive. 

Hmm..

Comment: I guess that response[0] is null, because 'passwd' is null.

Comment: passwd is globally maintained volatile, duly filled with decrypted password, in a synchronized code. i even did println in the beginning of the function, and also did a variety of tests and confirmed it is duly filled.

however, I was writing code to achieve the same end with few other libraries, that i have succeeded. but still i will try to fix this, and post the solution here, i am sure it will benefit someone, is they stumble upon the similar stuff.